# C# ASP.NET Make Relation Between GUID[Primary Key] and Integer

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, guid

Im confuse how to make relation between GUID and Integer, i have to retrieve **UserId** data from **CompanyID**[Integer] as seen below images ::

[This CompanyID Integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNVsh.jpg])

[This Id is a GUID type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZLNO.jpg)

I know INT and GUID is a different datatype, but how to make it relation[foreign key] ???

Basically what i need to do is **I need to show specific data to user that have specific roles** , i think this isthe only problem, make relation between this 2 different table.

u guys have any idea to solve this ? thank you

Comment: change the user id type to `Guid` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either GUID or INT for foreign keys, but they both have to be the same type.  You can't link a GUID to an INT.

You can either change one of the types, or add a new column with the same type.

Comment: so i cant link between 2 different datatype ? so why GUID has to be primary key

Comment: GUID is fine as a primary key, but your other table has to have a GUID as the foreign key as well.  You can also use INT as the primary key, which is a lot more common.

Comment: my team using mvc to develop this projects, did the GUID at above images generated when user register ?

Comment: I forget what the default type is for the different versions of the built-in membership systems, but it's possible it defaults to GUID.  You can change that, although it takes some effort to do it.